# Elements' styles are lost when app is deployed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, polymer

I have been working on a new version of my company's website using Polymer and Google App Engine. The design looks great on my local development server, but as it gets deployed polymer elements' styles are completely messed up.

**This is what it looks like when deployed to the app engine:**
http://data-buckeye-590.appspot.com/HTL

Any clues what might be causing it?

Comment: What I've noticed so far is that styles from a style-tag within the element or from a linked file are not being applied. ```<polymer-element name="....><template><style>...</style></template></polymer-element>```

Instead, if the styles are declared directly in the element tag, they work perfectly ```<div style="background-color:red;">...</div>```

Comment: Can you post a picture on what it looks like on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support Ryan. Got a tweet from @robdodson yesterday that solved the problem. Turns out that Google App Engine mod_pagespeed was messing up the internal styling of my polymer elements.

After turning off pagespeed on the application settings console the app is running as it should. But there is a catch!!!

It was impossible to find the pagespeed (enable/disable) checkbox on the new Developers Console https://console.developers.google.com

In order to turn pagespeed off it is best one visits the old application settings console at https://appengine.google.com/settings